# Does OAuth always presume a user interface?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I would like to connect to LinkedIn and extract some information via their API. The LinkedIn API uses OAuth 2.0.

All the documentation that I've read about OAuth (both in the context of LinkedIn and generically), seems to assume that there be a user interface in the form of the popup window which grants access.

However, in my case, I just want to export data via a command line application which will not have a user interface. What I'm really looking for is a simple way to *authenticate*, not *authorize*. The connection credentials will be in a config file.

Is OAuth what I want/need, or am I really looking for something else?

Comment: I believe this flow may be better for CLI apps because it doesn't assume a browser on the same device or anything about its capabilities: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices

Answer (score 3):

> Is OAuth what I want/need, or am I really looking for something else?

This depends on the API your are interacting with mostly. Looks like LinkedIn only works with OAuth2 (and 1, but being deprecated). So you have no other options.

OAuth is designed with delegation in mind. Who owns the information you want to extract from LinkedIn? The purpose of the UI flow is for the owner of the data to consent providing it to a 3rd party (your app). Often with a specific `scope` (e.g. access to profile, network, contacts, etc). The owner of the information authenticates and authorizes the disclosure of info to a 3rd party (your app). Your app authenticates too to LinkedIn (as a registered app) and then you call the API.

`refresh_tokens` are a vehicle to request new tokens without asking the user for a consent every time. These are relatively long lived entities that can be stored (and can be revoked by the user at any time).

If it is ***your*** data (you are both owner and 3rd party app), you could bootstrap your command line process with an initial authentication/authorization, and then you would keep it running with the `access_token/refresh_token`, until the refresh token expires.

Some system (not likely LinkedIn) support what is called the [Resource Owner flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#page-9). In which you can obtain an `access_token` through credentials (user/password). But nobody will likely relinquish their credentials to your app. (An exception is when you are both as I wrote above).

Comment: The data I want to extract is my own.